Conflict with another's team manager
I was working on a project with another team, and we were under a lot of pressure. After a heated argument (no raised voice or personal attacks), the other team's manager overreacted and removed me from the project abruptly, blocking all my access to work files.
When I tried to address the issue in a follow-up meeting, this manager accused me of unprofessional behavior, and of having a strong tone in my emails. I was just being direct, which is my usual communication style. Despite having valid points, I felt defeated, and the manager said he no longer trust me. I’ve been permanently removed from the project. I also suspect there might have been political motives behind this decision. But I don't have proof.
Now, I'm uncertain about what to do. My boss is supportive after I explained the situation. However, I feel unable to work with the other team members again. While I might be able to avoid them for a while, since I have other projects, the relationship between the teams is important. I'm concerned that my career here is over because I'll always be seen as a problem. Should I look for another job?

You just "being direct" doesn’t mean you were not also "having a strong tone in [your] email". If you don’t want this to repeat - be it at the current or next job - strongly consider to reflect on how you communicate with others. Even if you are technically correct, communication is not about getting information out but also across to someone else.

"However, I feel unable to work with the other team members again." - why is this?

@qwe, unless the things said were downright malicious lies, then you risk being seen as a bit of a prima donna to say you can't work with them ever again.

Your opinion on whether you "crossed the line"  is not the one that matters. Apologize, promise not to do it again, and next time do not let it get anywhere near that line.
Heated argument at work is always wrong. Quiet but confrontational is still wrong.
If they aren't under your direction, they are entitled to disagree with you. If you aren't under their direction, you can present your case to your manager and ask whether to do it their way (or do it at all); if your manager decides against you, at least your concern is on record.
Learning to accept and work with disagreement is a basic work skill. Always remember that you may be wrong, and that in most cases even if they're wrong it isn't a disaster. I spent many months doing a good implementation of a bad idea precisely to demonstrate why it was a bad idea; that's what management wanted, that's what I was being paid to do.
If you can't keep it calm, you have already lost and need to concede and walk away. If the other person's  perception is that you aren't keeping it calm, you need to accept that and find another approach. Fix that behavior, or the next job is likely to blow up the same way.

By definition they had the authority, or they could not have done it. It's done. Get over it, and next time don't give them the excuse.
